# Difference between bubble sort and gnome sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Bubble sort and gnome sort, they have the same complexity on worst, best, and average cases. What is the difference between bubble sort and gnome sort (not their names...)?

Comment: Homework? mark it as such, and show us what you've tried.

Comment: Actually not homework. Bubble sort was marked dumb by my prof. and gnome sort not mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

Okay i'm revising this post, as I didnt have much time for the last one but i realize that perhaps I should have explained more.

So basically. gnome sort is a variation of the insertion sort. While insertion sort goes through , say, an ENTIRE array of integers and places each element in its proper position, gnome sort tries to be more efficient and does the same thing but adds to this by looping back when a swap occurs, saving an iteration.

If that didnt make any sense, again, these articles would really help if you give them a glance.

For the insertion sort algorithm: http://codingmash.com/2012/07/the-insertion-sort-algorithm/

For the gnome sort : http://codingmash.com/2012/07/gnome-sort-a-variant-of-insertion-sort/

Hope it helped :)

Comment: That is untrue. The case is the exact opposite. Gnome sort is the less efficient one, which only steps back or forth only 1 index at a time, and insertion sort is the one which remembers the position from which it started iterating backwards.

Answer (score 2):

Incredibly detailed wiki articles exist for both [gnome sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnome_sort) as well as [bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort).

Comment: These articles explain it pretty well, and comparing the two definitions explains the difference. You can even look at the code and see the difference. @bdares is correct in asking for a little more explicit effort of what you have done SO is not meant to be a place where others do your homework for you :)

Comment: I actually successfully implemented both algorithm using C and Python, just felt them very similar.

Answer (score 1):

followed the link to gnome sort... i read one thing there which was quite good, that gnome sort does sorting like human beings do. Imagine yourself doing sorting of a list, thats what gnome sort is.

Answer (score 0):

Bubble sort is performed in nested loop but gnome sort is performed in a single loop.
Moreover, bubble sort compares adjacent elements in successive passes throughout the list whereas gnome sort compares adjacent elements back and moves the index back and forth. These are just two differences. rest are explained in the link given up.